# Unable to view restored site pages

Tags: sharepoint-2010, backup, sharepoint-designer, restore

I made a prototype of the SharePoint 2010 site in via the VirtualBox machine. I have successfully made a backup of the entire farm (all elements are backuped without errors).
After that I have restored the backup on another VirtualBox snapshot and on a real machine without errors (all elements were restored successfully).
However, when browsing some SubSites and their page, I receive the following error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

```
<nativehr>0x80070012</nativehr><nativestack>stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000CADB7) at 0x000007FEEEB6ADB7
stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000F7F3F) at 0x000007FEEEB97F3F...
```

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[

```
COMException (0x80070012): <nativehr>0x80070012</nativehr><nativestack>stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000CADB7) at 0x000007FEEEB6ADB7
stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000F7F3F) at 0x000007FEEEB97F3F
stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000F945B) at 0x000007FEEEB9945B
owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000B460F) at 0x000007FEEE2C460F
owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000C07CC) at 0x000007FEEE2D07CC
mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002BF827) at 0x000007FEF76AF827
Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000E6D39) at 0x000007FEEEA16D39
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001A4F67D) at 0x000007FEF2F6F67D
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001A1E9B6) at 0x000007FEF2F3E9B6
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001C0779E) at 0x000007FEF312779E
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001C080E4) at 0x000007FEF31280E4
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001F22EAC) at 0x000007FEF3442EAC
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001FD0545) at 0x000007FEF34F0545
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001FD2FBE) at 0x000007FEF34F2FBE
System.Web.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002C467F) at 0x000007FEF08C467F
System.Web.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002C447B) at 0x000007FEF08C447B
System.Web.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002C432A) at 0x000007FEF08C432A
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001FCFE7A) at 0x000007FEF34EFE7A
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001F21816) at 0x000007FEF3441816
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001F22D20) at 0x000007FEF3442D20
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001FCFF46) at 0x000007FEF34EFF46
Micros</nativestack>]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte& pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte& pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder) +589

[SPException]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +27254482
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte& pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder) +27641455
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, Byte& verGhostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId) +1750
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Byte& verGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes) +26195281
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformation(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Byte& verGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& level, String& masterpageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData) +388
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureContentFetched(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData) +364
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.GetFile(String virtualPath, Boolean fetchContent) +101
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetFile(String virtualPath) +78
   System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider.GetFileWithCheck(String virtualPath) +31
   System.Web.UI.DependencyParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath) +219
   System.Web.UI.DependencyParser.GetVirtualPathDependencies() +10955063
```

Some resource files imported via the SharePoint designer are unavailable as well.

Comment: First step is navigate to that site, and append the query string ?contents=1.  kill everything.  If the page loads, at least you've narrowed your problem down to a web part. check that you have all the same farm solutions deployed.  A good though annoying way of checking farm similarity is to run a compare of the directory system of /14/ compared between the two servers.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Yes, I have several WebParts restored within a backup. What do you mean by "kill everything"? WebParts? WSS_Content?

Comment: On that page, there is the option to close / delete the web parts on the page.  You can test if there is a problem with a web part by closing or deleting them on the ?contents=1 page.  Did it work?

Comment: I have tried this approach. WebParts are correct. The master page seems to be corrupted after restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by the fact that the v4.master Master Page of a specific SubSite is corrupted (and was missing after restoration... for some reason).
When opening a restored SubSite in the SharePoint Designer, the corresponding Design Time error message occurs.